# Defining pattern of text() node of complex mixed element

Tags: xml, xsd

This question is related to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381782/xml-schema-element-that-can-contain-elements-or-text) one. But somewhat extended.

Let's assume we have an xml:

```
<field name="test_field_0">
    Some text that is texty text.
    <subfield>Some text.</subfield>
</field>
```

The Scheme for it from [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381782/xml-schema-element-that-can-contain-elements-or-text):

```
<xs:element name="field">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="subfield" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Now the additional requirement is that `text()` node of `field` element should be regulated by some pattern, for example, this: `\p{Lu}(\p{Ll}\p{P}\p{Z})+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Schema does not allow to put any constraints on the text of an element that contains mixed content.