# Restricting an element to having text, or subelements

Tags: xml, xsd

We have a situation where we want to restrict an element to having:

- Either text(). or
- Subelements.

E.g.

```
<a>mytext</a>
```

or

```
<a><b>xxx</b></a>
```

But not:

```
<a>mytext<b>xxx</b></a>
```

Given the [xs:simpleContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376582/xml-schema-element-with-attributes-containing-only-text) mechanism I can restrict it to having only text, and of course I can define the element(s) it can be allowed, but does anyone know how I can combine the two to allow either text or subelements but not both?

Ta
Jamie

Comment: Exactly this questions was asked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381782/xml-schema-element-that-can-contain-elements-or-text. Not sure how I missed it! Vote to close if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is for you to use inheritance. Your resulting XML isn't as pretty, but you get exactly the content you want:

```
<xsd:element name="field" type="field" abstract="true" />
<xsd:element name="subfield" type="xsd:string" /> 

<xsd:complexType name="field" abstract="true" />

<xsd:complexType name="subfield">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="field">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="subfield" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="no-subfield">
  <xsd:complexContent mixed="true">
    <xsd:extension base="field">
      <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Then your resulting XML would contain the following (assuming you have `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declared somewhere)

```
<field xsi:type="subfield">
  <subfield>your stuff here</subfield>
</field>
```

or

```
<field xsi:type="no-subfield">your other stuff</field>
```

Most importantly, it disallows

```
<field xsi:type="subfield">
  Text you don't want
  <subfield>your stuff here</subfield>
  More text you don't want
</field>
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up - I was not aware of the inheritance mechanism.